# why is IsPresentItem giving me error in linklist?

Tags: c#, database

```
class LinkListGen<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        private LinkGen<T> list;

        public LinkListGen()
        {

        }
        public string DisplayList()
        {
          Console.WriteLine(test);
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                Console.Write(word + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
        public void AddItem(T item)
        {
            list = new LinkGen<T>(item);
        }
        public int NumberOfItems()
        {
            public int Count { get; }
    }
        public bool IsPresentItem(T item)
        {
            Link temp = list;
            bool result = false;
            while (temp != null)
            {
                if (temp.Data == item)
                {
                    result = true;
                    break;

                }

                else
                {
                    temp = temp.Next;

                }
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
```

I have been trying to make a generic link list but I am not sure why it is giving me an  error. The error is coming from the IsPresentItem. Also I'm not sure when I need to add to the linkListGen. thank you for your time

Comment: What is the error and where *exactly*?

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: A namespace cannot directly contain members and its also giving me the error on the list

Comment: The [class declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/class) is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You've got missing closing brace on the NumberOfItems method because you've declared the Count property within it:

```
public int NumberOfItems()
{
    public int Count { get; }
}
```

It should be:

```
public int NumberOfItems()
{
    //Do Something
}

public int Count { get; }
```

The whole class should then look like this:

```
class LinkListGen<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private LinkGen<T> list;

    public LinkListGen()
    {

    }
    public string DisplayList()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test);
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            Console.Write(word + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
    public void AddItem(T item)
    {
        list = new LinkGen<T>(item);
    }
    public int NumberOfItems()
    {
        //Do Something
    }

    public int Count { get; }
    public bool IsPresentItem(T item)
    {
        Link temp = list;
        bool result = false;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            if (temp.Data == item)
            {
                result = true;
                break;

            }

            else
            {
                temp = temp.Next;

            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: NumberOfItems() has closing braces, they are just a bit offset to the left

Comment: @styx I just pasted the code into a new class in VS and sorted out the problems - posting the result. There was a closing brace mismatch. I think it was caused by the Count property being inside the NumberOfItems method - which I assume was inadvertent by the OP